# AfterPublish target not working

Tags: msbuild, publish, task

World's simplest task (see below) is not being executed after I publish my web application project. Any idea why?

```
<Target Name="AfterPublish">
  <Copy SourceFiles="C:\A.txt" DestinationFiles="C:\B.txt" />
</Target>
```

Answer (score 38):

Note: The following applies to VS2010 and publishing web-application projects with the "Web Deploy" publish method selected in the 'Build/Publish {projectname}' dialog.

Julien Hoarau's correct in that "Publish" is NOT the name of the msbuild target invoked in the above case; the actual target name is **"MSDeployPublish"**.

Therefore, you have to define a **"Target"** element whose **"AfterTarget"** attribute's value is set to **"MSDeployPublish"** - the "Name" attribute's value does *not* matter (as long as it's unique among target names).

Here's how to do it:

- Open the project file (e.g. *.csproj) in a text/XML editor and, just before the closing `</Project>` tag, add a `<Target Name="CustomPostPublishAction" AfterTargets="MSDeployPublish">` element; pick a name of your choice for "CustomPostPublishAction".
- Add a so-called Task child element that performs the desired action; for instance, to add a command to be passed to cmd.exe, use an `<Exec Command="..." />` element.

Example:

```
<Target Name="CustomPostPublishActions" AfterTargets="MSDeployPublish" >
    <Exec Command="echo Post-PUBLISH event: Active configuration is: $(ConfigurationName)" />
</Target>
```

Note:

- In command strings, use XML entity(?) references in place of characters that would break XML parsing, e.g. "&gt" in place of "<".
- For documentation of the `<Target>` element in general, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t50z2hka.aspx
- Task-elements reference here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7z253716.aspx
- In general, if you need to determine the name of the msbuild.exe target that is actually invoked by Visual Studio 2010, do the following:

  - Go to Tools/Options..., Project and Solutions/Build and Run, select 'Detailed' (or, for even more information, 'Diagnostic') from the dropdown list labeled 'MSBuild project build output verbosity.
  - After running the build/publish action, e.g. Build/Publish, examine the Output window for the *last* occurrence of the string "Done building target" to determine the top-level target that was invoked.

Comment: Hi, Do you know if there is a way to make it work with FTP publish?

Comment: I would like to make this work for File System publish.. any ideia how? Thanks.

Comment: @MauricioRamalho: I suggest you ask a _new question_ (create a new post) with specifics. (I personally won't be of much help anymore, as I haven't worked with these things in years, but I'm sure someone will be able to help you.)

Answer (score 29):

Visual Studio 2013. Publish Web application to file system.

```
  <Target Name="Moose" AfterTargets="GatherAllFilesToPublish" >
    <Message Importance="high" Text="***Moooooooooooooooose***$(WPPAllFilesInSingleFolder)***$(TargetDir)" />
  </Target>
```

Note: Make sure that build logging is set to at least to Detailed. Look for it under Tools -> Options -> Projects and Solutinos -> Build and Run -> MSBuild output verbosity. Diagnostic is also fine if you want to investigate which build target was last run before actual publish.

Comment: This is the only target that fires for me in VS2015 when performing a file system publish of a web application project.  Neither MSDeployPublish nor AfterPublish work.

Comment: If you want thepath published to, use $(PublishUrl)

Comment: Yes ! That's the answer I was looking for, for so long !

Comment: According to this [MSDN forum link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/602198ff-17a3-43f3-9beb-26221e4fe6c7/afterpublish-target-not-working), it appears the only publish target available to web projects is `GatherAllFilesToPublish`.

Answer (score 8):

This seems to work in Visual Studio 2019

```
<Target Name="MyCustomTarget" AfterTargets="Publish">
  <Copy SourceFiles="C:\A.txt" DestinationFiles="C:\B.txt" />
</Target>
```

Answer (score 2):

- You must define override the target at the end of your file, after `<Import ... />`
- Launch MSBuild with detailed verbosity to see why your target is ignored :

  ```
  msbuild project.csproj /t:Target_to_Launch /v:d
  ```

`AfterPublish` is called after `Publish` target, but `Publish` is not the target called when you publish a web application. `Publish` is the target for publishing **ClickOnce** application.

You'll have to find the target used when you call `Publish` in Visual Studio, it could be `Package`, `WebPublish`...

Comment: Here are some highlights from the output:

Overriding target "AfterPublish" in project "c:\...\Microsoft.Common.targets" with target "AfterPublish" from project "C:\...\Ara.Web.csproj".

Target "_DeploymentUnpublishable" in file "c:\...\Microsoft.Common.targets" from project "C:\...\Ara.Web.csproj":
Task "Message"
  Skipping unpublishable project.
I can publish it from within Visual Studio, but the AfterPublish task is not working.

Answer (score -1):

I'm a little lazy right now to figure out the mess of targets to find the right one for a file-based publish (which you might be interested in).  What you can do in the meantime is defining an AfterBuild target in the *.pubxml file.

```
<Target Name="AfterBuild">
```

...

I recommend also turning off the property "DeleteExistingFiles" because if you copy files into the directories being published, it does a clean somewhere during the publishing process.

```
<DeleteExistingFiles>False</DeleteExistingFiles>
```