# running an AfterPublish command in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3, publish

I tried adding this code to my project file:

```
<Target Name="AfterPublish">
<Exec Command="start C:\test.txt" />
</Target>
```

This doesn't fie up at all. When I do "AfterBuild" though, it works fine. So, what I think it is, that my publish is not set to "Web Deploy". Does anyone know if there is a way to make the "AfterPublish" work without publishing using Web Deploy setting.

Comment: take a look at this [post][1]. I think it will help a lot. Cheers!


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561689/afterpublish-target-not-working