# After database publish event visual studios

Tags: visual-studio

So I have been searching for awhile but cant seem to find a solution.  I have a visual studios database project and I need to run a command (sqlmetal) post publish.
I found this [After Publish event in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13781799/after-publish-event-in-visual-studio) but it didnt really help me as mine is a database project.