# Is there a way to execute a command after publishing (file system method) is complete?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, publishing

I need to execute commands after all the files have been published on the server.
I am using the file system method to publish from Visual Studio, and the .NET Framework 4.7.1.

I have tried to edit the .pubxml file, and added a simple message to show when an target (event) is triggered, but none of the target i tried seems to trigger after all the files are published, it always trigger before or never.

This one works but is triggered just before the files are copied on the server

```xml
<Target Name="CustomPostPublishActions" AfterTargets="PipelineAspNetCompileMergePhase">
  <Message Text="************ Test 01 ************" Importance="high"/>
</Target>
```

I also tried the "MSDeployPublish" target, and it is never triggered.

Is there one target i didn't find ?
And if there is not, is there another way to do it ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13781799/after-publish-event-in-visual-studio

Comment: @TrevorBrooks You are right, if it was not possible (and for now it is), i was going to do the same as this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/50927887/8782945