# How to define an event after publish

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, .net-5

In Visual Studio 2019, you can define events to be run after **BUILD** ("Post-build"), but can you define also an event after **PUBLISH**?

I am publishing a .net 5 single-file (Windows Desktop App), which is in fact an exe file. I want to digitally sign the exe with a tool before it is finally released. How can I automate this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [After Publish event in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13781799/after-publish-event-in-visual-studio)

Answer (score 1):

you can use msbuild target to execute a task after the project is published and invoke a command to sign you executable file.

edit you `csproj` file and add the following msbuild target

```
<Target Name="Sign" AfterTargets="Publish">
    <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(PublishDir)" Command="{your signing tool command here}" />
</Target>
```

save your file and run `dotnet publish` the signing command will be executed after the publish is finished