# How to publish project to folder and sign

Tags: c#, visual-studio, publish

I have a solution that contains a console (or Winform) application and I use
Visual Studio **publish to folder**.

My problem is that we need to sign (certify) the *.EXE file.
Currently I do that manually. I'm not using ClickOnce and no setup-project.

Is there a way to publish to folder and sign the resulting *.exe file at once?

Comment: Have you tried adding a "Post-build" Build Event? (See Project Properties)

Comment: I have tried, but it does not work.

Comment: Could you add what you tried so far (code?) and how it did not work (error message etc.) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use "SignTool" to sign:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/signtool-exe

Edit your *.csproj file and add code like this:

```
<Target Name="CustomAfterPublish" AfterTargets="Publish">
            <Message Text="Sign Publish EXE"      />
            <Exec Command="call c:\SignTool\signtool.exe sign /tr http://timestamp.digicert.com /td sha256 /fd sha256 /f c:\YourSingFolder\YourCertificate.pfx $(PublishDir)$(TargetName).exe" />
</Target>
```

Some background information here: [After Publish event in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13781799/after-publish-event-in-visual-studio).