# Post-build event command for publish (Visual Studio 2010)

Tags: visual-studio-2010, publish, post-build-event

I have a project in visual studio 2010.
This project has the following post-build event command lines:

```
SET TARGET_PROJECT=TestMain
IF NOT EXIST "$(TargetDir)IceBox" (
  XCOPY /E /I /Y "$(SolutionDir)Externals\IceBox" "$(TargetDir)IceBox"
)
IF NOT EXIST "$(TargetDir)bzip2.dll" (
  COPY "$(SolutionDir)Externals\IceBox\bzip2.dll" "$(TargetDir)"
)
XCOPY /E /I /Y "$(SolutionDir)Externals\Infragistics" "$(TargetDir)"
```

But this commands are just used when I create a debug or a release. When I publish my project will this commands ignored.
Gives it a possibility to use this commands when I publish the project?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Perhaps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561689/afterpublish-target-not-working will be of use

Comment: The solution above did not work ok. But this one did: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19456112/afterpublish-script-doesnt-run-when-i-publish-a-web-app

Answer (score 11):

I recently faced a similar problem. I wanted to run a command 'only' if I published the application and not with every build.

I added a post publish [task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171466.aspx).
Since I don't use [MSBuild](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd637714.aspx) directly I modified my solution csproj file.

*Example:*

***Solution Name:*** MyKillerApp

***Project File name:*** MyKillerApp.csproj

Open the file with Notepad++ or other text editor and navigate to the end of the file and find this section(should be almost at the end):

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <PreBuildEvent>
    </PreBuildEvent>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Then add your postpublish task

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <PreBuildEvent>
    </PreBuildEvent>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Target Name="AfterPublish">
    <Exec Command="..\..\Documentation\DoxyGenExe\createDocs.bat" />
  </Target>
```

My task runs a bat file that runs [Doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/) (a very nice docs creation program) and some other tasks.

You can create a bat file to run any commands is very handy